# Trying make join to get data about people flying on Mars

Tags: postgresql, join

Trying make join to get data about people flying on Mars

I'm having studying database, which contains information about different flights on spaceships. I will provide you with my database for better understanding.[My datalogical model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC8gR.png)

The task is - find the amount of people that flew to a certain point on a certain ship. I do it with the code shown below:

```
select ship.shipname, destination.name as destination_name, count(person_id)
from person
        join flight_person on flight_person.PERSON_ID = person.ID
        join flight on flight.id = flight_person.flight_id
        join ship on flight.ship_id = ship.id
        join destination on flight.destination_id = destination.id
group by ship.shipname, destination.name;
```

The output is next:

| shipname | destination_name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WhiteForest | Mars | 1 |
| YarikLightSpeed | Earth | 1 |
| YarikLightSpeed | Mars | 2 |

But the problem is, that I want to get information about points and destinations that I didn’t visit, how can I modify my query to get this data. In my case with is destination Neptune and snip FirePower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, what you're looking for is called "FULL JOIN". In this case, you'll get an output, which contains all information about all ships and all planets. Consider following example:

```
select ship.shipname, destination.name as destination_name, count(person_id)
from person
    join flight_person on flight_person.PERSON_ID = person.ID
    join flight on flight.id = flight_person.flight_id
    full join ship on flight.ship_id = ship.id
    full join destination on flight.destination_id = destination.id
group by ship.shipname, destination.name;
```

| shipname | destination_name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | Neptune | 0 |
| FirePower | null | 0 |
| WhiteForest | Mars | 1 |
| YarikLightSpeed | Earth | 1 |
| YarikLightSpeed | Mars | 2 |